# Starting a new shopify session from shopify_token and shopify_domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-activemerchant

I have a user_id attached to the Store model for a Shopify App.  I want to be able to have a user login with their user account to have the shopify session start instead of using needing to open the app from their app section of their store. This is a standalone app btw.

I have tried this for when users sign in:

```
if Shop.find_by(user_id: current_user)
  shop = Shop.find_by(user_id: current_user)
  shop = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(shop.shopify_domain, shop.shopify_token)
  ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(shop)
end
```

and:

```
if Shop.find_by(user_id: current_user)
  shop = Shop.find_by(user_id: current_user)
  shop = ShopifyApp::SessionRepository.retrieve(shop.id)
  ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(shop)
end
```

I tried this in my session create method and as a after_action callback for the create method in the sessions controller...

Is there something I am doing wrong?

I tested this in console to make sure all of the assocations were correct.  The token and shopify_domain are all there attached to the user

Comment: There is a pretty high probability that your current_user is jack all nothing. Otherwise, that code would work. Investigate that. You provided no details on your data, so lets assume you never checked any of it for validity.

Comment: By jack all nothing, what do you mean exactly? I tested the associations in the console and they appear.   I guess ill try by hard coding the records and see what happpens... But when i sign in through the email, it still redirects me to enter the shopify domain, then it works.  I'm about to test if the webhooks are working to make sure it's still connected that way.  I noticed when i log out of the devise sessions, it kills the shopify session as well and disconnects it.

Comment: You are juggling a lot of code you never wrote, expecting it to just work. At some point you need to debug a simple thing. If for example you login some user in your Rails App, and that is failing, then debug. Are you finding a Shop? No? Then current_user does not exist for a shop. What is current_user? You get it?

Anyway, your question is not really a question. What is your actual real question?

Comment: It seems the new way to do things is by doing `session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(domain: shop.shopify_domain, token: shop.shopify_token, api_version: '2019-04')` but this gives me error : `NoMethodError (undefined method "strip" for #<Hash:0x000055b6d43b93a0>)` from here: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/lib/shopify_api/session.rb

Comment: I also tried coding the domain and token directly into the session and it still would give the same error

Comment: While signing in with a user that doesn't have a Shop attached i get `ShopifyAPI::Base::InvalidSessionError (Session cannot be nil)` ...